# Convergence of a modified power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n $$ is a (uniformly) convergent complex series converging to $f(z)$ in a certain region $|z|\leq R.$ Is it always the case that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{n+1}}z^n $$ is convergent? Can we find the limit in terms of $f$ and $a_0$. I would be highly obliged for any help.

Comment: Hmm, the absolute value is disturbing without having absolute convergence of the first one, but maybe it is true, I have not dived into it yet.

Comment: Indeed, the problem reduces to $z=R$ (the positive real number), since if it converges there then it converges absolutely for all $|z|\le R$.

Comment: I think it is a hard problem. With no loss of generality we may set $R=1.$ Assume the conclusion is true, i.e the series $\sum |a_n|(n+1)^{-1/2}$ is convergent for any function in the space $U$ consisting of the power series convergent uniformly in $\{|z|\le 1\}.$ The mapping $U\to \ell^1$ given by $f\mapsto \{a_n(n+1)^{-1/2}\},$ where $f=\sum a_nz^n,$  has closed graph, hence is bounded. Therefore $$\|f\|_\infty \le C\sum |a_n|(n+1)^{-1/2}$$ for a universal constant $C.$ Now the problem is to decide whether this is true for polynomials.

Comment: @What if $a_i's $ are the coefficients in the Maclaurin series of an entire function?

Comment: Then there is no problem whatsoever, as $|a_n|^{1\over n}\to 0.$

Comment: Can you briefly explain why

Comment: The radius of convergence is then infinite hence  $a_nz^n\to 0$ for any $z.$ Thus $|a_n||z|^n\to 0.$ In particular $|a_n||z|^n\le 1$ for $n$ large enough. Thus $|a_n|^{1/n}\le |z|^{-1}$ for $n$ large enough. Hence $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}\le |z|^{-1}.$ As $|z|$ is arbitrary, then $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=0,$ i.e. $\lim |a_n|^{1/n}=0.$

Comment: Lots and lots of thanks for such an elegant explanation